# How to install mod_authz_host in Apache?

Tags: 12.10, apache2

When I put

```
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
Allow from dev.example.com
```

into `/etc/apache2/conf.d/restrict.conf`, upon `service apache2 restart` I get

```
Syntax error on line 1 of /etc/apache2/conf.d/restrict.conf:
order not allowed here
Action 'configtest' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
   ...fail!
```

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is not that mod_authnz_host isn't installed or loaded, but that you put these directives in the wrong place. They are only valid in `<Location ...>` or `<Directory ...>` blocks like this:

```
<Location />
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from dev.example.com
</Location>
```

Comment: lol thanks.  i tried copying right out of the docs  http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/access.html  silly me.