# Enable access from my Public IP instead of localhost via Apache 2.4

Tags: networking, 14.04, apache2.4

I have Ubuntu 14.04 , apache  2.4.7

```
$ apache2 -v
Server version: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
Server built:   Apr  3 2014 12:20:28
```

I made many attempts to  access from my public IP

Firstly , i enable  authz_host :

```
$ sudo a2enmod authz_host
```

Then , i follow [this issue](https://askubuntu.com/questions/262981/how-to-install-mod-authz-host-in-apache) to configure Apache :

Unfortunately, i don't find the file whose path  : 
/etc/apache2/conf.d/restrict.conf

My question : What's the new config file to allow access from Public Ip.

That it means : Be able to Access :

either by: `http://localhost/myProject`

or by :  `http://87.x.x.x/myProject`

Comment: Have you configured your router to redirect the http port to your machine?

Comment: My router is a hotspot . It is an issue of Apache ,Sure 80%